# What makes OSX say that it's low free space on the boot volume for the program memory?

Tags: macos, mail.app, memory

I had 3 GB of free space on my 32G SSD drive when I decided to do an index rebuild in my apple mail. It ate up all the free space. I connected an external drive and moved some applications to free up another 3GB. I redid the rebuild and it ate up another 3GB. Then I moved the V2 folder from my
 home library (mail folder) to the external drive and created a symlink. I relaunched the mail, launched 'rebuild' and during reindexing it popped up a window saying that my boot volume doesn't have enough free space for the system memory, while in fact I have somewhat 15 GB of free space on my main drive. And 1.5TB on the external drivre. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

First off, "system memory" does not necessarily refer to available hard disk space. It sounds like you don't have enough free hard disk space on your system disk to rebuild Mail's index. One thing to note is that an index rebuild is usually done by making a clean copy of the index, keeping the old file around until the rebuild is complete. Even if you've symlinked the file to the external drive, the index may be a separate hidden file on the SSD.

If the message truly did refer to "system memory," it's also possible that you ran out of swap space, which can only reside on the system disk.

Move as much as you can off the SSD and try one more time. You may also want to look around for the files caused by the failed index rebuilds and delete them (making sure, of course, you do not delete the real one).

Comment: I am not sure about the wording of this message in English (it was in Russian). When doing rebuild for the second time I kept open the windows displaying free space both on my system drive and on my external drive, they both were far from being fully used (22GB).
How do I check the swap space? 
Right now I am thinking of making an 'archive' mailbox and moving all the messages older than three years to that archive. I guess this rebuild reffers to just one mailbox at a time. Thus this could help.

Comment: I forget now where the swapfile resides, but it should shrink as needed, or at the very worst after a reboot.